# MS Access Dlookup

Tags: ms-access

I am using Dlookup in access module.

below is the code

```
ivar = "Editalbum"
ovar = DLookup("[ofield]", "[tblone]", InStr(1, UCase(ivar), UCase(ifield)) > 0)
```

My table(tblone) has 2 fields **ofield** and **ifield**, ofield contains the output I am trying to get so what i am trying to do is find

**Album**(*ifield*)

in

**Editalbum** (*ivar*)

and if found give me the ofield value. But with the code above I am getting incorrect output, basically it's giving output from first row of the table all the time.

Comment: Dlookup will return a field value based on a WHERE criteria. Your criterial is related to ifield. what type of data is ifield?  [Application.DLookup Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-dlookup-method-access)

Comment: Thanks for your response. ifield is short text. Actually in Dlookup I am using instr to find ifield text in a variable ivar.

Comment: Well, that won't work. You must type a WHERE criteria on ifield. Something like`"[ifield]='" & whatever you are looking for & "'"`. Check the link i posted before. Right now, with Instr you just obtain a number, but you said ifield is short text. That never will work.